# What is the wrong with my code in dafny?

Tags: dafny

I try to use dafny to verify the correctness with my qsort function, but idk why there are verified failures about my code. 
Here is my code:

```
    method Testing (a: array<int>)
      requires  a.Length > 0
      modifies a
    {
        qsort(a,0,a.Length-1);
        var i :int := 0;
        while(i<a.Length-1)
          decreases a.Length - 1 - i
        {
          assert a[i] <= a[i+1];
          i := i+1;
        }
    }
    method qsort(a: array<int>,left: int,right: int)
        requires left>=0 && right < a.Length
        modifies a
        decreases right - left
    {
      if (right > left)
      {
          var pivotValue: int := a[left];
          var t: int := a[left];
          a[left] := a[right-1];
          a[right-1] := t;
          var storeIndex: int := left;
          var i :int := left;
          while i < right - 1
            invariant left <= storeIndex < right
            decreases right - i
          {
              if a[i] < pivotValue
              {
                t := a[storeIndex];
                a[storeIndex] := a[i];
                a[i] := t;
                storeIndex := storeIndex+1;
              }
              i := i+1;
          }
          t := a[right-1];
          a[right-1] := a[storeIndex];
          a[storeIndex] := t;
          qsort(a,left,storeIndex);
          qsort(a,storeIndex+1,right);
      }  
    }
```

The errors are:

1. assertion violation

   ```
   assert a[i] <= a[i+1];
   ```
2. This loop invariant might not be maintained by the loop.

   ```
   invariant left <= storeIndex < right + 1
   ```
3. failure to decrease termination measure

   ```
   qsort(a,left,storeIndex);
   ```

   Thanks to the answer from @James Wilcox, I rewrote my code as:

   ```
   method qsort(a: array<int>,left: int,right: int)
   requires left>=0 && right <= a.Length
   ensures (exists p | left<=p<right :: (forall k: int :: left < k < p ==> a[k] <= a[p]) && (forall j: int :: p < j < right ==> a[j] >= a[p]))
   modifies a
   decreases right - left
   {
     if (right > left)
     {
         var pivotValue: int := a[left];
         var t: int := a[left];
         a[left] := a[right-1];
         a[right-1] := t;
         var storeIndex: int := left;
         var i :int := left;
         while i < right - 1
           invariant left <= storeIndex < right
           invariant storeIndex <= i
           decreases right - i
         {
             if a[i] < pivotValue
             {
               t := a[storeIndex];
               a[storeIndex] := a[i];
               a[i] := t;
               storeIndex := storeIndex+1;
             }
             i := i+1;
         }
         t := a[right-1];
         a[right-1] := a[storeIndex];
         a[storeIndex] := t;
         qsort(a,left,storeIndex);
         qsort(a,storeIndex+1,right);
     }  
   }
   method Testing (a: array<int>)
     requires  a.Length > 0
     modifies a
   {
       qsort(a,0,a.Length);
       var i :int := 0;
       while(i<a.Length-1)
         decreases a.Length - 1 - i
       {
         assert a[i] <= a[i+1];
         i := i+1;
       }    
   }
   ```

   But the postcondition of qsort may not hold, what can i do to correct it?

My final verified code:

```
    method qsort(a: array<int>,left: int,right: int)
        requires 0<= left <= right <= a.Length
        requires  0 <= left <= right < a.Length ==> forall j:: left <= j < right ==> a[j] < a[right]
        requires  0 < left <= right <= a.Length ==> forall j:: left <= j < right ==> a[left-1] <= a[j]
        ensures forall j,k:: left <= j < k < right ==> a[j] <= a[k]
        ensures forall j:: (0<= j < left) || (right <= j < a.Length) ==> old(a[j])==a[j]
        ensures 0<= left <= right < a.Length ==> forall j:: left <= j < right ==> a[j] < a[right]
        ensures 0< left <= right <= a.Length ==> forall j:: left <= j < right ==> a[left-1] <= a[j]
        modifies a
        decreases right - left
    {
      if (right > left)
      {
          var pivot := left;
          var i :int := left + 1;
          while i < right
            invariant left <= pivot < i <= right
            invariant forall j::left <= j < pivot ==> a[j] < a[pivot]
            invariant forall j::pivot < j < i ==> a[pivot] <= a[j]
            invariant forall j::0 <= j < left || right <= j < a.Length ==> old(a[j])==a[j]
            invariant 0 <= left <= right < a.Length ==> forall j:: left <= j < right ==> a[j] < a[right]
            invariant 0 < left <= right <= a.Length ==> forall j:: left <= j < right ==> a[left-1] <= a[j]
            decreases right - i
          {
              if a[i] < a[pivot]
              {
                var count :=i -1;
                var tmp:=a[i];
                a[i] := a[count];
                while (count>pivot)
                  invariant a[pivot] > tmp
                  invariant forall j::left <= j < pivot ==> a[j]<a[pivot]
                  invariant forall j::pivot< j < i+1 ==> a[pivot]<=a[j]
                  invariant forall j::0<=j<left || right <= j <a.Length ==> old(a[j])==a[j]
                  invariant 0 <= left <= right < a.Length ==> forall j:: left <= j < right ==> a[j] < a[right]
                  invariant 0 < left <= right <= a.Length ==> forall j:: left <= j < right ==> a[left-1] <= a[j]
                  {
                    a[count+1]:=a[count];
                    count:=count-1;
                  }
            a[pivot+1]:=a[pivot];
            pivot:=pivot+1;
            a[pivot-1]:=tmp;
            }
              i := i+1;
          }
          qsort(a,left,pivot);
          qsort(a,pivot+1,right);
      }  
    }
    method Testing (a: array<int>)
      requires  a.Length > 0
      modifies a
    {
        qsort(a,0,a.Length);
        var i :int := 0;
        while(i<a.Length-1)
          decreases a.Length - 1 - i
        {
          assert a[i] <= a[i+1];
          i := i+1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code may be correct, but Dafny typically needs some help in order to prove it.

1. Dafny will only reason about method calls by their postconditions (`ensures` clauses). Since your `qsort` method has no postcondition, Dafny will assume it can do anything. This explains why the `Testing` method fails to prove the assertion. If you add a postcondition to `qsort`, then you will have to prove it! That will be a good exercise!
2. Dafny reasons about loops in terms of their invariants. If a variable that is modified by the loop body is not mentioned in the loop invariant, Dafny assumes its value is arbitrary. Your invariant about `storeIndex` is not true if, somehow, `i` was smaller than `storeIndex`. You can fix this by adding the additional invariant `storeIndex <= i` to the loop. Then both invariants will pass.
3. The previous fix also fixes the termination problem.

In order to better understand how Dafny uses pre/postconditions and loop invariants to break down the verification problem, I suggest you read [the guide](https://rise4fun.com/dafny/tutorialcontent/guide). Then you can add a suitable postcondition to `qsort` and try to prove it using additional loop invariants. Feel free to ask more questions if you get stuck!

---

In your second version of your code, the postcondition seems too weak, since `qsort` is a *sorting* method, it seems the postcondition should be that the array is sorted. (Since it is recursive, actually the postcondition should only talk about the region of the array between `left` and `right`.) If you do this, then the assertion in `Testing` should pass. You will then still have some work to do to prove the postcondition for `qsort`, by adding invariants to the while loop inside it.

Comment: At first, thanks for your help! But i still have 2 two questions that i don't understand... 1. I have add the invariant(storeIndex<=i) you mentioned and it works! But how can it be wrong when I have already initiated i before the loop? 2. I try to ensures qsort with `ensures forall k: int :: 0 <= k < a.Length-1 ==> a[k] <= a[k+1]` , but it seems to be wrong since it is recursive? I can't think of a better postcondition... And i did read the introduction of the guide yesterday but there are so many things it did't tell me :(

Comment: I rewrote my code with the help of your answer but it still doesn't work...

Comment: You should continue working through the guide, especially the sections on pre/postconditions and loop invariants. To answer your followup questions, the program is correct with or without the loop invariant, but the *verification* problem is determined by the loop invariants. In other words, you have to help Dafny out by giving it the invariants. For your second question: try to reformulate the postcondition using left and right instead of 0 and a.Length-1

Comment: I have posted my new code in question description. The post condition of qsort means there is a pivotIndex that divides the array into two parts, one of it satisfies that all the numbers within it are smaller than pivotValue, and the other part is the bigger one. It uses left and right but still, it may not hold somehow.

Comment: I updated my answer with a few thoughts about your new code.